# My Github pages website is not loading my assets folder

Tags: reactjs, github, webpack, deployment, github-pages

Link: https://valenguerra.github.io/valenguerra

Repo: https://github.com/valenguerra/valenguerra

I am developing a React Webpack portfolio using [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages).

From the chrome developer tools, looking in the "source" tab, you can see there is no assets folder. Which means that the assets folder is not making it to the deployed version.

Not sure if its a problem with webpack or gh-pages configuration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that you're referencing the assets from the root, e.g. `<img src="/assets/images/profile.png" ...`, while your assets get published to **valenguerra/assets**, so the path should be `/valenguerra/assets/images/profile.png`

Comment: @tromgy Thanks a lot, it worked. For development in localhost, should I create a "valenguerra" folder with the assets folder inside?

Comment: This will probably be the simplest solution. But you could also use a .env file with a variable that can determine the path.